# Calling an instance from a symbol

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to get this line to work, and it just won't do it.  Can't figure it out.

```
pumpkinPage.this ["textBox" + i] = currentGuess;
```

That doesn't work, but if I do it like this

```
pumpkinPage.textBox0 = currentGuess;
```

it works fine.  How do I get the first line to work?

Comment: This is messy.. what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What error are you getting?

Assuming `pumkinPage` is a dynamic object (Object, MovieClip etc), `pumpkinPage["textBox" + i] = currentGuess;` should work.

Comment: C:\Users\coder.RCC402-11\Desktop\andrewGleasonHangmanAssignment\Main.as, Line 116 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before this.
C:\Users\coder.RCC402-11\Desktop\andrewGleasonHangmanAssignment\Main.as, Line 116 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightbracket.

are my errros